# Runtime array that calculates sum and average of float data types

Tags: java, arrays, floating-point, java.util.scanner

Having trouble creating a program that creates an array size at run-time, displays the array size, rounds the sum and average of numbers to two decimal places.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * Java Program to take array input from the user using Scanner.
 */

public class runtime_array {

public static void main(String[] args) {

//display message

System.out.println("Program creates array size at run-time");
System.out.println("Program rounds sum and average of numbers to two decimal 
places");
System.out.println("Note: numbers *must* be float data type");
System.out.println(); //blank line

 // taking String array input from user
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter length of String array");
float myFloath = input.nextFloat();
int  num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0;


// create a String array to save user input
String[] input = new String[length];

// loop over array to save user input
System.out.println("Please enter array elements");
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  String userInput = input.next();
  input[i] = userInput;
}

System.out.println("The String array input from user is : ");

int sum = 0;
int average =0;
```

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input));

Comment: So you have trouble, OK. Can you tell us with what exactly?

Comment: Specifically having difficulty creating an array where the user decides how many elements it contains. And how to append the scanner input to float user input

Comment: @AlexMarr look at the code I posted. It creates an array, populates the array and formats the data printed to the console to 2 decimal places. Compare it with your code and look at what your doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the length of an array is an int, not a float.

Second, you have to actually use the userinput that you just got and not `length`.

third, you should use a float or double array to perform your operations, but for that you need to typecast the input.

```
 // taking Int array length input from user
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter length of the array");
int arrayLength= input.nextInt();

// create a array to save user input
float[] input = new float[arrayLength];
```

I suggest you look up all the terms you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Program creates array size at run-time");
    System.out.println("Program rounds sum and average of numbers to two decimal places");
    System.out.println("Note: numbers *must* be float data type");
    System.out.println(); //blank line

    // taking String array input from user
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter length of String array");
    float length = input.nextFloat();

    // create a String array to save user input
    String[] arr = new String[(int)length];

// loop over array to save user input
    System.out.println("Please enter array elements");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String userInput = Float.toString((input.nextFloat()));
        arr[i] = userInput;
    }

    float sum = 0;

    System.out.println("The String array input from user is : ");
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", Float.valueOf(arr[i])));
        sum += Float.valueOf(arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + String.format("%.2f",sum));

    System.out.println("The average is: " + String.format("%.2f",(sum/length)));
}
```

this should work, although i have not tested it.

Comment: so this is what I have so far. The only error I keep getting is that the variable arr isnt defined.

Comment: @AlexMarr You have quite a few errors in your code. Using a variable that wasn't defined, allocated or created, Having lots of extra unused variables, Logic errors, just to name a few. But based on the description you gave, and the code you posted, all I did was fix the errors in your code and provide you a working example. If you don't want me to fix your code and only want to know what the errors are, then please be more specific in your questions.